# Why 'Maximum number of redirects exceeded' error when connecting to the OpenAI API

Tags: redirect, openai-api, chainlink

When I attempt to use the following code to interface with the OpenAI API by chainlink functions, I encounter an error stating 'Maximum number of redirects exceeded'. Here is the code I am using:

```
const prompt = args[0]

if (!secrets.openaiKey) {
  throw Error("Need to set OPENAI_KEY environment variable")
}

const openAIRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${secrets.openaiKey}`,
  },
  data: {
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: prompt,
    temperature: 1,
    max_tokens: 512,
  },
})

const [openAiResponse] = await Promise.all([openAIRequest])
console.log("raw response", openAiResponse)

const result = openAiResponse.data.choices[0].text
return Functions.encodeString(result)
```

The error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kAHf.png)

I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this prompt is "Say this is a test in one line"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the error is caused by some syntax error in the request itself. Can you try to adjust your code to look like this?

```js
const openAIRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${secrets.openaiKey}`,
    },
    data: {
      "model": "text-davinci-003",
      "prompt": prompt,
      "temperature": 1,
      "max_tokens": 512,
    },
  })
```

(Notice quotes around `Authorization`, `model`, `prompt`, `temperature`, and `max_tokens`)

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience. I have attempted to execute the code provided, but I'm experiencing the same result. Could there potentially be another issue we might need to address?

Comment: Do you use a free or paid OpenAI API key?

Comment: paid OpenAI API. When I curl it in my  terminal, it's success.

Comment: have you tried with generating a new API Key?